# Ошибка Java * What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'

Tags: java, reactjs

Создаю приложение на react native.
При сборке приложения просит JAVA.
Установил JDK 10 и при компиляции выходит ошибка * What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.

Как понимаю, нужно более старую версию java ставить?
Пойдет ли 8 версия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Java 8 будет работать, но вроде [пишут](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16536#issuecomment-341425396), что можно просто Gradle обновить:

В **/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** написать:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-all.zip
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @md5hash рад, что помогло ^_^